# Applying Nested filter in React-kendo-grid

Tags: node.js, reactjs, kendo-grid

I want to apply nested filters on columns so that user can apply multiple filters in the same column using **kendo-react-grid**.There are examples by using **Kendogrid** but not in **kendo-react-grid** npm.Really appericate for example.

[image: Nested filter in kendo Grid i want same filter in React-kendo grid]

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, the Kendo suite for React does not have menu package. It is in the [official roadmap](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/roadmap/), and expected the upcoming release.
The Filter Menu of the Grid is also [planned](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-react/issues/28) and will be released right after the menu is done.